# Visual studio cordova app build is failing

Tags: android, apache, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Google Sdk adb fastboot usb driver installed.. there is no issues and even not alerting any error message but app build is failing..

There is no use even after installing CTP 3.1 for VS 2013.

Kindly help me on it

Comment: Does this issue occur for blank new project? Could you please describe more about the detailed actions you have done? The usb driver will be used only when you try to debug on device. Did you see any error if you rebuild the solution in VS?

Comment: No actually, I am getting the issue while deploying the solution to device. As Subhag Oak says I already checked and I am able to see my device there. But unexpectedly it was terminating the deploy process.

Answer (score 0):

As Alan says, VS will try to launch the app on the device if you have selected the "device" option and are trying to run or debug the app on the device. Does building to Ripple work? If its failing only for device, Can you please attach the complete build log?

VS uses ADB to connect to the device and so even though you have installed the driver, the ADB might not be able to see the device.

Can you run the following command to see if ADB lists the connected device:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices

Also please check whether your device shows up in the windows device manager.

Let me know what you find.